# How to decode information which is embedded in computer screen from its partially captured photo?

Tags: security, image-processing, computer-science, steganography

I have an idea to prevent leaks of confidential data from camera captured photo of the document.
This is the main scenario.
This software will be installed in user's computer.
And when the computer is turned on, the software will be autorun and that computer's device ID and user ID will be encrypted as the format of image for example.
Let's assume that information thief will capture the computer screen with his camera.
I need to retrieve user identity from captured photo.
For the implementation of this idea, I think these following steps are main focus.

1. Embed user identification data in computer screen as the format of steganography
2. Decode embedded information from camera-captured photo.

My biggest concern is how to make embedded information(user id, for e.g) be invisible to user.
Second concern is how to decode original information from partially captured photo.
My possible solution to second concern is hologram.
It is known that hologram can be reconstructed from its portion.
But the problem is that hologram will be too visible to users.
It is trade-off, if I increase hologram visibility(maybe transparency) the possibility of its reconstruction will be increased, but its bad to user-friendly.

Any ideas or possible solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: Your second concern should be your primary concern. And the answer to that is: **forget it**. When someone takes a photo of a computer screen you have to worry about scaling, orientation, rotation, lighting, camera quality, and any artifacts produced by capturing a screen. QR codes address most of those problems, but guess what? They're super visible. And there is a reason for that.

Comment: @Longguo Small portion of the hologram provides a blurred scene reconstruction, and as the area of the portion grows, the scene is reconstructed with more and more detail. You can increase the frequency of hologram, and then decrease opacity of hologram to make it invisible to user. After that you can use high pass filter to retrieve hologram.

Comment: @Reti43, thanks for your prompt response.
why QR codes should be visible, what is the reason for that?
What do you think about HOLOGRAM as the solution to my "primary" concern?